# 05132: Some off facing?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, anagram

You open a file and see the following codes. What do they mean?

```
05132: Some off facing
6309: A salmon sandwiching
32001: Be laid bacon
24322: A hi conveys
5039: Rebirth solved
66622: Tried oozing
63142: Abandon prows
41622: Honesty fool
0099: Noisily cut pluck
```

It's more-or-less impossible to solve without a hint, so here's the first one.

Hint 1:

> Each number corresponds to its phrase in a certain way. All phrases together form a list of some sort, and all items in the list have something in common (which is why they can be arranged).

Hint 2:

> If I generated the same file a few years later, its contents may be different.

Hint 3: Since this puzzle hasn't got any up-votes yet (but 57 views), it doesn't seem too popular. So here's the third hint already.

> Yes, I just gave you the third hint. You didn't see it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The numbers correspond to

> Reversed ID numbers of puzzles on this site created by user [Gamow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8874).

The phrases are

> Anagrams of phrases that relate to each puzzle.

The complete list:

> 05132: Some off facing  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Game of coffins ([How to beat Count Dracula](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23150))
>  6309: A salmon sandwiching  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Dancing animals show ([The lion and the zebras](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9036))
>  32001: Be laid bacon  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Bob and Alice ([The subtraction game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10023))
>  24322: A hi conveys  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Heavy coins ([Thirty genuine and seventy fake coins](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22342))
>  5039: Rebirth solved  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Devil's brother ([The Devil's Brother](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9305))
>  66622: Tried oozing  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ No zero digit ([The largest Monday number](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22666))
>  63142: Abandon prows  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Pawns on board ([A lonely pawn on the chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24136))
>  41622: Honesty fool  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Lots of honey ([Winnie-the-Pooh and the 27 honey pots](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22614))
>  0099: Noisily cut pluck  $\;\;\;\rightarrow\;\;\;$ Unlucky politics ([Thirteen politicians](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9900))

They are ordered by

> number of votes, descending.